# How to set bufferpool to 8K on SQL server 2005 database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to set bufferpool to 8K on SQL server 2005 database

Answer (score 1):

A buffer pool of 8k would fit exactly 1 (one) data page. No can do.

You can configure the buffer pool size by changing [max server memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx). The minimum is 16 Mb, and is highly recommended you do not touch this setting at all.